# eclipse + tomcat deploying: missing directory

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I created a directory under WEB-INF in my application (i m using Eclipse + Tomcat),
but when i try this `servletContext.getRealPath("/")+"images/"+image;`.

I get an error saying that directory `images` do not exist.

I verified the `workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\ecommerce_2011` directory and i didnt found the images directory, thats weird, why it's not deployed with other directories? any solutions?

Comment: How are you deploying your application? I mean: how are you copying files to Tomcat?

Comment: Print out what that path actually is or step to it in a debugger.  I'll bet the reality does not match your assumptions.

Comment: automatically by using eclipse wtp

Comment: Have you done a Clean Tomcat Work Directory and republish?

Comment: `getRealPath("/")` won't do anything regarding `WEB-INF`--if you want `WEB-INF` in your path, you need to add it. You'll also need to not deploy using a war, and not directly serve the images in WEB-INF from TC, as files under WEB-INF aren't directly accessible from clients. IMO images should go either in your web app root (unless you're deploying a war) or in another, external location.

Answer (score 0):

I think images directory should go inside your web app directory not inside WEB-INF.

Comment: what about `servletContext.getRealPath("/images/"+image);`? http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29